# How to remove duplicates for columns

Tags: vba, excel

Edit: Realised I asked the question too Broad so I have changed the data to specify. Apologise for that. I have sample data like this:

```
J1_D2   J1_D3   J1_D2   J1_D2
J1_D4   J1_D7   J1_D7   
J1_D9   J1_D11  J1_13   J1_14
'
'  
'
```

I have no idea which row or column the data ends. The data will have Capital Letters and Underscore. The data starts at Column D but I would not have idea which column it ends. 
I want to remove the duplicates for the different columns on each row so  it will end up like:

```
J1_D2   J1_D3    
J1_D4   J1_D7   
J1_D9   J1_D11  J1_13   J1_14 
'
'  
'
```

Update: I have tried the answers given below. It didn't remove some of the data correctly. I think it must have been because of the Capital Letters in the data

```
Dim r As Range, c As Range
Dim d As Object
Dim ret, i As Long

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

On Error Resume Next
Set r = Application.InputBox("Select Range", "Remove Duplicates by Row", , , 
, , , 8)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not r Is Nothing Then
For i = 0 To r.Rows.Count - 1
    For Each c In r.Offset(i).Resize(1)
        'If Not d.Exists(c.Value2) Then d.Add c.Value2, c.Value2 '~> case sensitive
        '/* below is a non-case sensitive comparison */
        If Not d.Exists(UCase(c.Value2)) Then d.Add UCase(c.Value2), c.Value2
    Next
    ret = d.Items()
    r.Offset(i).Resize(1).ClearContents
    r.Offset(i).Resize(1, UBound(ret) + 1) = ret
    d.RemoveAll
Next
End If
```

Comment: The code will work in your set of examples or in any set of example. It seems your problem is your data entry which have trailing spaces. :)

Comment: Yup just realise it just now too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
Dim lr As Long, lc As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To lr
    lc = Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For j = lc To 1 Step -1
        If Application.CountIf(Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, lc)), Cells(i, j)) > 1 Then
            Cells(i, j).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
        End If
    Next j
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

As per your new sample data if your data starts from column D, you need to change the code to this...

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
Dim lr As Long, lc As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To lr
    lc = Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For j = lc To 4 Step -1
        If Application.CountIf(Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, lc)), Cells(i, j)) > 1 Then
            Cells(i, j).Delete shift:=xlToLeft
        End If
    Next j
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You can try the code in the file uploaded here...

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fqeqqrjieqizc8y/RemoveDuplicates%20v2.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: It doesn't do anything .

Comment: How? I ran the code on your sample data and it returned the desired output you have shown in the description. Can you share a screenshot of your data or a sample workbook?

Comment: Remember the code assumes that your sample data is in the range A1:D3. Is it right?

Comment: Sorry i can't show you the data. Yes, I place the data in that way still nothing happened

Comment: Check this file. Click the button Remove Duplicates on the sheet to run the code. https://www.dropbox.com/s/amdakjbhf5xrz5k/RemoveDuplicates.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Hi, I have tried it on the link you sent me and it works fine. I have no idea why when I copied it to my excel worksheet. It doesn't work with the same data on the same row & column

Comment: Where have you placed the code? It should be placed on a Standard Module. In the file I attached, replace the existing data with your data and run the code by clicking the button and see if that works this time.

Comment: Sorry but what does standard module means ? I place in worksheet. Is that wrong? Am I suppose to place it in a module ?

Comment: I have tried it in the file you attached. I am really sorry for not specifying the question but the data has Capital Letters. So it did not remove the data correctly. Can u extend the row to the end of the row instead ?

Comment: I have edited the answer and provided the link to DropBox file. Try the code in that file. A Standard Module is like Module1, Module2 etc. which you get after inserting a New Module. On VB Editor --> Insert --> Module and paste the code into the opened code window.

Comment: I realise that my data had spacing in front, " J1_14" thats why the code couldn't work ! Now it works fine ! thank you so much :)

Comment: You're welcome Rachel! Glad it worked ultimately for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Added explanation. Best way is to step through each line by pressing F8. But first, open the locals window to see what's happening on the variables.

Try this:

```
'/* declarations */
Dim r As Range, c As Range
Dim d As Object
Dim ret, i As Long

'/* create and assign dictionary object which will be used in removing duplicates */
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'/* call Input box method type 8 which accepts Range Objects and assign to variable */
On Error Resume Next '/* Needed in case invalid or no selection was made */
Set r = Application.InputBox("Select Range", "Remove Duplicates by Row", , , , , , 8)
On Error GoTo 0 '/* reset the error handling so other errors are trapped */


If Not r Is Nothing Then '/* Test if r is assigned successfully */
    For i = 0 To r.Rows.Count - 1 '/* iterate the rows of the selected range */
        For Each c In r.Offset(i).Resize(1) '/* iterate per cell of that row */
            'If Not d.Exists(c.Value2) Then d.Add c.Value2, c.Value2 '~> case sensitive
            '/* below is a non-case sensitive comparison */
            If Not d.Exists(UCase(c.Value2)) Then d.Add UCase(c.Value2), c.Value2
        '/* used dictionary object method Exists to determine duplicates */
        Next '/* repeat until all values on the target range is checked */
        ret = d.Items() '/* assign the unique items to array */
        r.Offset(i).Resize(1).ClearContents '/* clear the existing content of the target range */
        r.Offset(i).Resize(1, UBound(ret) + 1) = ret '/* assign the new contenst */
        d.RemoveAll '/* clear the existing items in dictionary object */
    Next '/* repeat the process for the next row */
End If
```

This will let you select the range then remove the duplicates on the selected range by row.

Comment: @RachelChia I tested it using your given set of data and it works :). If you have a different set, then that is out of scope. What I meant is, this does not include the method of comparison on the values (binary,dbase  or text). You can try to incorporate that in above code. Btw, do not misunderstand me answering your question. I would've voted to close it but thought it was an interesting question. You know the drill in SO in formulating questions. You've been around for awhile but you might want a [tour](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Sorry, I have been here a while but I didn't really know what to ask and what not to ask so I have no idea what drill or anything. I didn't take the tour. I took it as a platform to ask questions for programming. I will try to improvise the code so mind explaining the codes?  Thanks

Comment: @RachelChia That's good to hear :). Anyways, if you can revise your question to discuss your `specific` issue, we would be very happy to help. As is, your question is really broad (reason why you got 2 close votes). Add what have you tried and failed, what sample data you're working on (or if it is confidential create something that is similar).

Comment: @RachelChia Added explanation on the code. My bad for not explaining it. Btw, you can also open the locals window and run the code line by line using F8 in VBE (Visual Basic Editor) to understand the code better. Also, all the methods used can be googled, it's not that hard :).

Answer (score 0):

Find the first and last value range and use the below code

```
Sub RemoveDuplicatesCells()
'PURPOSE: Remove duplicate cell values within a selected cell range

Dim rng As Range
Dim x As Integer

'Optimize code execution speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Determine range to look at from user's selection
  On Error GoTo InvalidSelection
    Set rng = Selection
  On Error GoTo 0

'Determine if multiple columns have been selected
  If rng.Columns.Count > 1 Then
    On Error GoTo InputCancel
      x = InputBox("Multiple columns were detected in your selection. " & _
        "Which column should I look at? (Number only!)", "Multiple Columns Found!", 1)
    On Error GoTo 0
  Else
    x = 1
  End If

'Optimize code execution speed
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Remove entire row
  rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=x

'Change calculation setting to Automatic
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Exit Sub

'ERROR HANDLING
InvalidSelection:
  MsgBox "You selection is not valid", vbInformation
  Exit Sub

InputCancel:

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, i want to remove the duplicates for the different columns maybe i didn't explain clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your data needs to be in columns. (You may use transpose formula to do the necessary.) You can then go to data tab of Excel, click on Filter Advanced, select table range, give copy range, select Unique records and finally click okay.
If necessary use transpose formula once more.